# Xcode performance testing failure percentage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I am performance testing a function using `XCTestCase` [measure(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure).

If the percentage increase in time (from the set baseline) is 62% worse, the test still passes:
[image]

However, if the percentage increase in time is 65% worse, the test fails:
[image]

and the failure message says "**(max allowed: 10%)**"

**My questions**:

1. Does the "max allowed: 10%" message imply the test should have failed in the first case when the time increased by 62%?
2. Is the max allowed increase officially documented anywhere because I can't find it in any official documentation.
3. Is there a way to customize the max allowed percent increase? I see there is a way to adjust the max STDEV, but that's not what I mean.

**Note**: In all my testing it appears that if `(%increase - STDEV) >= 60%` the test will fail, otherwise the test will pass.